# Android Kotlin, shuffle recyclerview list

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, shuffle

I want to have a button where I shuffle my list in a random order. I do not want to have a new list.
Button is pushed(onclick.listener???) my list Animals will shuffle, (Collections.shuffle???)

Below is an image of the app, button will be on top next to home.

Below is my current code.

class BvocabanimalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var mAdView : AdView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.bvocabanimal)

    

    val btnMoveActivity3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)

    btnMoveActivity3.setOnClickListener {
        // Creating an explicit intent
        intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    val myDataset = Datasource().loadAnimals()

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rec2)
    recyclerView.adapter = ItemAdapter2(this, myDataset)

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

}

I have tried a few different things and searched plus watch videos but still having trouble.[image: animals apps image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put the **myDataset** variable in class level scope instead of function scope. And keep the reference of **ItemAdapter2** in class level variable like **myDataset**.

Now, If user click the button, shuffle **myDataSet** using [shuffle](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html) function.

```
myDataSet.shuffle()
```

Finally update **ItemAdapter2** data source and call **notifyDataSetChanged()** of **ItemAdapter2**

Kotlin docs: [shuffle](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html)